# Stored procedure returns ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

On **MySql 5.7**, I'd like to run this procedure which is supposed to fetch `tag1` of articles from `article` table and insert them into `article_tag` table:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dt1()
BEGIN
DECLARE maxid INT;
DECLARE x INT;
 DECLARE tag1 VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE ntag1 int;
SET maxid = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `article`);
SET x = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM ` article`) ;
    WHILE x<= maxid DO 
       SET tag1 = (SELECT tag1 from `article` WHERE id=x);   
       call debug_msg(TRUE, tag1);
       SET ntag1 = (SELECT count(*) from `article_tag` WHERE tag=tag1);

       IF ntag1 = 0 THEN INSERT INTO `article_tag` (tag, slug, frequency) VALUES (tag1, tag1, 1);
       ELSE UPDATE ` article_tag` SET frequency = frequency + 1 WHERE tag=tag1 ;
       END IF;
              SET  x = x + 1; 
  END WHILE;
END$$
```

I can confirm than none of the `tag1` values is null:

```
    SELECT count(*) from `article` WHERE tag1 IS NULL;
    +----------+
    | count(*) |
    +----------+
    |        0 |
    +----------+
```

However when I run the procedure, I get:

> ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'tag' cannot be null

Here is a reproducible example.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ymPtabSksRUMSBep7SyX8/5

This problem bugs me for hours. So appreciate on hints on why this happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: this is NULL `SET tag1 = (SELECT tag1 from article WHERE id=x);`

Comment: @AlbertoMoro why is it null?

Comment: Don't give declared variables the same name as columns - change the declared variable tag1 throughout your code to vtag1 and it should work.

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks a lot! This trick worked like a magic. Please answer with explanation and I'll accept.

Comment: It's not a trick mysql simply cannot distinguish between columns and variables (and parameters) with the same name. It's up to the coder to provide that information.

Comment: I could not figure that out in a million year. Thank you.

Comment: This SP can be replaced by a single [IODKU query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4nLzWVif3a7mmazSPGVh2H/0).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Will you please elaborate what is `IODKU query`

Comment: **I**nsert ... **O**n **D**uplicate **K**ey **U**pdate